# How to determine whether a reaction is possible by using a phase diagram?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, phase

Given the following phase diagram for a binary mixture of $\ce{MoO3}$ and $\ce{Bi2O3}$:

[image]

I am asked to determine whether from $\ce{Bi2O3}$ and $\ce{Bi6Mo2O15}$, can $\ce{Bi10Mo3O24}$ and $\ce{Bi14MoO24}$ be synthesized? And why?

I have checked the given answer and it says the 1st reaction is possible, and the second one isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: E.g. write `$\ce{H2SO4}$` or `$\ce{a A <=> p P}$` or `$\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$`  to get $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{a A <=> p P}$ or $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ (all eventually with double dollars in the display mode like $$\ce{H2SO4}$$.

Comment: Given an appropriate mixture of the two, either can be made with some effort, since those compositions fall between your two given phases. We’re there other restrictions?